# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

'I have build maven project using java 8 and tomcat 8 and configured sonar with jdk 11. but I am getting below error after running command mvn sonar:sonar
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project **project-name** : Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000: Connection refused

please help'

Comment: Is that the right URL for the Sonar server?

Comment: in setting.xml I have provided this info : <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
  <profiles>
 <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
                <sonar.host.url>
                  http://localhost:9000
                </sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
  </profiles>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SonarQube - Failed to connect to > localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325811/sonarqube-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-000000019000)

Comment: No It is not answering my question.

Comment: Network issue ...or the SonarQube server is not correctly configured..

Comment: @pooja is the sonarqube is running in the same machine where the  `mvn sonar:sonar` command is ran?

Comment: yes everything is at local.

Comment: Hi every one your consolidate solutions worked for me and problem solved sonar server took much more time to start up. Thank you very much guys....